# Enviar correo con python desde heroku

Tags: python-3.x, flask, heroku, gunicorn

la idea era usar el correo electrónico para recibir las peticiones de los formularios en un sitio web. Como mi aplicación usa Python, use el módulo "yagmail" para enviar los correos, pero Heroku me marca un error 500. En el localhost, la aplicacion de correos funciona bien

```
    nombres = request.form['nombre']
    correo = request.form['correo']
    numero = request.form['numero']
    direccion = request.form['direccion']
    mensaje = request.form['mensaje']
    tipo = request.form['tipo']
    ciudad = request.form['ciudad']
    barrio = request.form['barrio']
    localidad = request.form['localidad']

    sujet = "Msg MandalUSS peticion: " + tipo
    cont = nombres + " :: " + correo + "\ntel/cel: " + numero + "\nmensaje: " + mensaje + "\nciudad: " + ciudad + "\nbarrio: " + barrio + "\nlocalidad: " + localidad + "\ndireccion: " + direccion

    correo = yagmail.SMTP('correo@example.com', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    correo.send(to = "asrielx2019@gmail.com", subject= sujet, contents = cont)

    return "<script>alert('Su peticion se esta revisando. por favor espere un correo o llamada de verificacion.'); window.location.assign('/');</script>"
```

Comment: Podrías poner el traceback completo del error? Esta en los logs de heroku

Comment: smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv\n5.7.14 I-Fx63MyV3eUfeZITNYAJmEw87bkRzUKQK0jaiIZ1tkrGNtxNjhy4dTAU2x-4r3pIzAI-\n5.7.14 lWaxwkRvJFkMZdXzec8lBXE3ehmzcvmRsl4OgPoCkB12KU3V4dknYm8CFZxx3hdP>\n5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 y22sm3194760qka.18 - gsmtp')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dos posibles razones asumiendo que el usuario y contraseña usados son correctos:

- Como SMTP no utiliza la verificación de dos pasos de Google, tienes que verificar que
  este permitido el [acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) en tu cuenta. Debería
  estar **activado**.
- A veces Google bloquea el acceso desde una IP desconocida, en ese caso deberías entrar
  a [DisplayUnlockCaptcha](https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) y seguir
  las instrucciones.

[Fuente](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229)